# How to tell if 74HC595 is dead

Tags: shift-register, atmega328p, fault

I just bought a few SN74HC595N and they are doing some weird stuff. I was testing them and output just does not come out. I know it's not a problem with my circuit, since I had a couple laying around and have tested them with a simple binary counter. This is it with the ones that work. It's powered from 5V, updated by a custom class running on an ATMega328p, and the resistors are 1kΩ.

[image: working binary counter]

If I swap the right register for one of the new ones, something weird happens:

[image: problem chip]

The LEDs driven by the old one are still working, so \$Q_H'\$ is clearly working. But the other outputs \$Q_{A,B,\dots,H}\$ are completely blank. Is this just a clear case of busted output transistors or is there something I'm missing? Because the 10 chips I got are like this, so It's pretty frustrating.

Is there any test I could do to check if this is just dead or if there's some other behavior that has been changed in a recent revision?

The packages are a little different, by the way:

[image]

Old one is above, new one is below. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got the OE pin pulled low?

Comment: Please ask a specific question, you'll get better answers

Comment: @HandyHowie it certainly looks like he has.

Comment: Without bypass capacitors, performance on a breadboard will be unreliable. Add ceramic 0.1uF capacitors with very short legs very close to the power supply pins of the IC.

Comment: When you have a case where say the left chip appears good and the right chip appears bad, swap the chips (left <--> right) instead of introducing a 3rd (unknown) chip. If the error moves with the chip, you've got a bad chip. If error stays on the same side then it's a breadboarding problem.

Comment: Where did you buy it? Can you provide a photo that shows the markings (and less wood)? It's possible that you got a fake.